# Cauchy sequnce, how do they get from this step to the next?

Tags: calculus

I have here part of a solution to a problem using Cauchy sequences, but I'm stuck as to why a^(m-1)+...a^n ends up being less than a^m-a^n/(1-a) ? Any help on seeing this?[image]

Comment: Do you know the sum of geometric series?

Comment: Use the dollar sign '$' to enclose math part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $$a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}+\cdots+a^n=a^n\left(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{m-n-1}\right).$$ You will recognise this as the sum of a geometric series, with common ratio $a$, and $m-n$ terms.

Hence, $$a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}+\cdots+a^n=a^n\left(\frac{1-a^{m-n}}{1-a}\right)=\frac{a^n-a^m}{1-a}.$$